# How Jupyter Notebook communicates with Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, cluster-computing

I have installed multi-node Spark Cluster on VirtualBox. Everything looks great my master and slave nodes are working.However, I could not connect to the Cluster in VirtualBox with the Jupyter Notebook installed on my computer.The code below doesn't work.What can I do?

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Test") \
.master("spark://MyMasterAddress:7077") \
.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Hi John! Welcome :) Could you include the output of any error messages you are getting?